python function: argument after argument with asterisk
I was wondering why defining the following function is considered fine.
def foo(*x, y):
    pass

As far as I know there is now way of calling this function, since it's always missing the value for y. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)
Does this have any utility I'm not ware of?

There's no way to provide a positional value for y in that function, but you can certainly still pass a keyword parameter.

Note: going to the toilet solves most problems...
You can call it with foo(1, y=2). But still, this means y MUST be an positional argument

@FrontendC  And that is expected behavior.  You can specifically make a function where all parameters are keyword only by putting * in the first position.  You can also force parameters to be positional only by using / after them. def func(pos_only, /, pos_or_keyword, *, keyword_only):

See the Rationale in PEP 3102 – Keyword-Only Arguments.
